# jQuery unable to get the id if image is deselect

Tags: jquery

I want to integrate image selector in my code. This is get the values of the images selected however, when an image is deselected, I'm unable to get the value OR remove the value from the array. Below is my code in HTML:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".selectable").selectable({
    selected: function() {
      var selectedItemList = $("#selected-item-list").empty();
      $(".selectable img").each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).hasClass("ui-selected")) {
          selectedItemList.append((index + 1) + ", ");
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.selectable .ui-selecting {
  border: 2px dashed #ff0000;
}

.selectable .ui-selected {
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}

.selectable img {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

.selected-items {
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
  line-height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />

<div class="selectable">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/190x190/2c488f/ffffff&text=Image+1" class="ui-widget-content" />
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/190x190/522F93/ffffff&text=Image+2" class="ui-widget-content" />
</div>

<p class="selected-items">You have selected the following images: <span id="selected-item-list"></span></p>
```

Comment: How do you deselect an image? You don't appear to have any logic for that

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You are correct. I don't know the option. Can you guide me on this?

Comment: So your question is instead 'how do I deselect an image'?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I can deselect an image from browser, but unable to remove the value from the array. You can see the same from https://codepen.io/codesnips/pen/QNYoyv . Once I deselect an image, the values in array remain the same.

Comment: You're not deselecting any images there...? The output is always correct for the chosen images. It's really not clear what the problem is or what you're asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `unselected` similar to `selected`.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".selectable").selectable({
    selected: function() {
      var selectedItemList = $("#selected-item-list").empty();
      $(".selectable img").each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).hasClass("ui-selected")) {
          selectedItemList.append((index + 1) + ", ");
        }
      });
    },
    unselected: function() {
      var selectedItemList = $("#selected-item-list").empty();
      $(".selectable img").each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).hasClass("ui-selected")) {
          selectedItemList.append((index + 1) + ", ");
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.selectable .ui-selecting {
  border: 2px dashed #ff0000;
}

.selectable .ui-selected {
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}

.selectable img {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

.selected-items {
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
  line-height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />

<div class="selectable">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/190x190/2c488f/ffffff&text=Image+1" class="ui-widget-content" />
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/190x190/522F93/ffffff&text=Image+2" class="ui-widget-content" />
</div>

<p class="selected-items">You have selected the following images: <span id="selected-item-list"></span></p>
```